# How do i show the below proof

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, toeplitz-matrices

Let Tn and  Tn' be Toeplitz matrices generated by f(θ) and f(θ + θ'). Show that for n > 0,  Tn' = ΩnTnΩn where Ωn = diag(1,e−iθ',e−2iθ',...,e−i(n−1)θ').

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: MathJax, please.